# How to pattern match == and =?

Tags: elixir

Playing around with Elixir.  Consider this scenario.  I have

```
iex> a = b = 1     #=> a = 1, b = 1
iex> c = true
iex> a == b        #=> true
iex> true = c      #=> true
```

Therefore I assumed the below would return true, but got illegal pattern.

```
iex> a == b = c  
** (CompileError) ... illegal pattern
```

Comment: The same is true in Erlang. Doing `1 == 1 = 1.` in `erl` will give an illegal pattern error. `1 == (1 = 1)` works.

Comment: True. What I tried doing is `((a==b)=c)` rather than `(a==(b=c))` that would return false.

Comment: @Gazler: I am doing `1 == 1 = true` not `1 == 1 = 1` as per your comment

Answer (score 1):

When using the `=` operator, you are using the **match** operator, which performs **pattern matching** and not an **assignment**.

The way the `=` operator works is this:

```
pattern = expression
```

At runtime, the left side is matched to the right side. So, the left side is called a **pattern**, whereas the right side is an Elixir term **expression**.

Even though I would not be able to throw a formal definition of what a **pattern** is, I can tell you that it is not the same as an **expression**. As the **`illegal pattern`** error states, there are more restrictions to what a **pattern** can be.

In general, a **pattern** can use compile-time constructs, but no runtime values. 
You can use base types constructors such as tuples (nested or not), lists, maps or even constants as **patterns**.

For instance these are valid **patterns**, given those variables are unbound:

```
{:ok, content}

[head | tail]

1

x

{:ok, { day, month, year }, { hour, minute, second} }
```

However, the following are runtime expressions that aren't legal **patterns**:

```
1 == 1

a + b

true != false

a == b
```

You can use this kind of expression on the right hand side with no problem, but not on the left hand side.

An exception to this would be the `++` and `<>` operators, as they automatically translate to constructor styles (for instance `"hello" <> "world"` is the same as `<<"hello", "world">>`)